# Falling back on default values - better coding practice

Tags: java

When falling back on default values (in the below case name "John Doe"), which code appears better from the readability and possibly performance point of view:

```
String name;
if(last != null && first != null) {
    name = last + first;
} else {
    name = "John Doe";
}
```

Or a case without else statement:

```
String name = "John Doe";
if(last != null && first != null) {
    name = last + first;
}
```

Does any of the above approaches have any significant drawbacks in your opinion?

Comment: I prefer 1st variant, as you can declare name as final and thus avoid potential problems in future

Comment: Have you considered the ternary operator?

Comment: I don't like ternary operators with multiple conditions, I think it is the worst from readability perspective. Can you provide an example of the above code that you consider good in a form of ternary expression?

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is the second option, because of two reasons:

- it is shorter - less code to maintain the better
- definition of a local variable without an assignment is a code smell - it always raises the question "is the current code guaranteeing a value is assigned to this local variable"?

In terms of performance, you need to measure it, but I bet the Java Virtual Machine is able to optimise both of the above approaches and there are no significant differences in execution.